# Start() Error In Powershell (Starting a Shortcut)

Tags: powershell, arguments, startup

I have created a Powershell script to do a timed restart on my server.  This is a snippet of my code and more specifically the startServers Function.

I have added the global variables into the function in an effort to have an example.

Basically each server name is the name of a shortcut that starts an exe in a separate directory.   The names are exactly that and have no .lnk after (I have tried both ways).

The aff array is for processor affinity.

This script should:

1. For Each Server
2. Create a New Sysem Diag Process with start info
3. Start the process
4. Set affinity

This is not the case: I get an error revolving around the "arg0" and it not being able to start the process. I suppose if anyone has some further explanation of what is going on with args0 and what it is would be helpful.

Code Snippet:

```
function startServers
{
    #Added For Example Purposes 
    $servers = @( "public", "private" ) 
    $aff = @( 196, 56 )
    #End

    $i = 0
    foreach($s in $servers) 
    {
    $app_name = "$s"
    $a = $aff[$i]
    $app_arguments = "arg0"
    $pinfo = New-Object System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo
    $pinfo.Arguments = $app_arguments
    $pinfo.FileName = $app_name
    $p = New-Object System.Diagnostics.Process
    $p.StartInfo = $pinfo
    $p.Start()
    $p.ProcessorAffinity=$a
    $i = $i + 1
        #Start "$s"
        Write-Output "Starting $s"
    }
}
```

[image: The Error I Get]

Comment: @Matt foreach ($s in $servers) This would define $s and make it that instance of the loop so it would be $servers[0] then $servers[1]

Comment: Post the full error you get

Comment: You have tried to post this code before then since i recognize it. .... what are you trying to `Start` a server name?

Comment: @Matt I have posted a bit of it, but I don't think my start method was as far along as this. I actually found this from another post here.  I will not credit myself for it.  I was hoping to find more info on how this works.  The server name is public.exe  that is where the lnk takes it.  Basically there are args in the target line of the shortcut that need to be used to have the server start correctly.  However it doesn't appear this wants to start up with a shortcut, but notepad works.

Comment: @Matt I updated with the full error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function startServers {
    $i = 0
    $global:pids = @( )

    foreach($s in $servers)
    {
        $a = $aff[$i]
        $Starter = Start-Process -FilePath $s -WindowStyle Minimized -PassThru  
        $Process = Get-Process -Id $Starter.ID
        $global:pids += $Process.ID
        $Process.ProcessorAffinity = $a
        $CurrentTime = updateTime
        Write-Output "Starting $s at $CurrentTime"
        $i = $i + 1
        Start-Sleep -s 10
    }
    return
}
```

This is how I ended up solving the problem.  I switched over to tracking the process by PID.

I used -PassThru on my Start-Process and I made it a variable.

I then made a variable that would hold the PID after it was started called Process.

Then you do the basic $foo.ProcessorAffinity = foo and you get your result.